# Помогите сделать slick slider

Tags: html, slick.js

Мне нужно что бы у этих двух блоков (где картинка и где текст) работали как единый slick слайдер
Можно ли сделать так: каждый блок сделать слик слайдером и привязать к ним одну кнопку переключения, или нужно как-то по-другому?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ ---> Slider Syncing

Comment: @Elena Так я и хочу его использовать, как мне привязать два блока к одному слайдеру ? Что бы Не полностью экран менялся, а только Фото и текст

Comment: смотрите пример Slider Syncing , создаете слайдер изображений и слайдер текста и связываете их между собой

Comment: @Elena Спасибо, помогли))